# Is there a way to have a Webkit browser within an AIR app with JS/HTML only?

Tags: javascript, html, air, webkit, adobe

I want to build an AIR app and embed a webkit browser while not using flex/flash, just Javascript and HTML. Is it possible? If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK AIR includes a webkit instance, so you can definitely make html-based AIR apps, here's Adobe's instructions for doing it in Dreamweaver:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f7f.html

and here's how to do it with the SDK:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: I want to actually display a browser inside my app and control it's navigation and his javascript env. via javascript.

Comment: So instead of using their browser, they use your app which is a clone of their browser? why would they do that? ... btw, you can edit your question with the link below its tags.

Comment: Well, I want to create an application where users can write apps for. Those apps are going to be written in HTML, CSS, Javascript and so on. That's why I need a browser inside the app that can be controlled from my host application - just like Spotify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. There's no need to embed WebKit, as it's [baked into Adobe AIR.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime#Application_development)

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: I want to actually display a browser inside my app and control it's navigation and his javascript env. via javascript.